# parse image position as a variable

Tags: php, html

Hi
I am writing a php code and and am supposed to display a large number of images on the webpage and hence I am using mysql data base to store the coordinates and taking them using SELECT and then trying to position them.

But I am not able to parse the cordinate as variable.

```
echo "img style=\"position :absolute; top:123px;left:123px\" border=\"0\" src=\"throbber.gif\" alt=\"Image\"/>";
```

in this place I want to do:

```
echo "img style=\"position :absolute; top:$variable1 px;left:variable2 px\" border=\"0\" src=\"throbber.gif\" alt=\"Image\"/>";
```

Please help me with this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
echo '<img style="position:absolute;top:'.$posX.'px;left'.$posY.':px;border:none;" src="throbber.gif" alt="Image" />
```

Note that you need to start the `<img>`-tag with a `<`. I moved the `border`-attribute to CSS (styles do not belong in markup) and used single quotes (`'`) instead of double quotes (`"`), to prevent clashes inside the string (escaping sequences are rather ugly to read). Besides that, i used string concatenation (operator is `.`) to add the variables to the string.

Answer (score 0):

Since there shouldn't be a space between the variable and the "px" you could use the **concatenation operator** "." for doing this.

It works like this:

```
$a = "hello";
$b = 10;

echo $a . $b; // Output: hello10
```

So

```
echo '<img style="position: absolute; top: ' . $variable1 . 'px; left: ' . $variable2 . 'px;" border="0" src="throbber.gif" alt="Image">';
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use curly brackets around the variables:

```
echo "<img style=\"position: absolute; top: {$variable1}px; left: {$variable2}px\" border=\"0\" src=\"throbber.gif\" alt=\"Image\"/>";
```